# How to match a video with a text file containing time stamps in windows forms application

Tags: winforms, media

I have a simple use case. 
I have a video which has been recorded. And a corresponding text file containing timestamp(per second) which containes certain value depending on time. 
Now I want to add this text file as a subtitle on the media file. What will be the best way to do this in windows forms application. 
Please comment if you need more information.

Following is the format of the text file.

```
DATE 13/08/03 
TIME 13:15:27 
0 mA
0 mA
0 mV
DATE 13/08/03 
TIME 13:15:27 
0 mA
0 mA
0 mV
DATE 13/08/03 
TIME 13:15:28 
0 mA
0 mA
0 mV
DATE 13/08/03 
TIME 13:15:28 
0 mA
0 mA
0 mV
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never played video on forms, but there must be some control for it. 
I'ld read the subtitles file into a list of SubtitleEntity objects.

This could be one entity's structure:

```
DATE 13/08/03 
TIME 13:15:27 
0 mA
0 mA
0 mV
```

Then use a simple label under the video, or on the video if you can do that, the rest is just time calculations.